# Connecting to domestic flight in Auckland (AKL), do I have to re-check-in my luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, auckland

When flying from Hong Kong to Queenstown, there is a two hour layover in Auckland, changing from the international terminal to the domestic one.

I am wondering whether my bags will be checked through to Queenstown or do I have to pick them up in Auckland and the check them in again for the domestic flight?

Both flights are with Air New Zealand.

The airport's [website](https://www.aucklandairport.co.nz/AirportInformation/International-terminal/International-arrivals.aspx), seems to say I need to collect and re-check in but I was wondering about any personal experiences from people.

Comment: Re view from local flight. Try for window seat and not over wing :-). - Note where Taranaki (Mt Egmont) is and look for it on way down. You will not see it if flight path is straight over mountain but it also can be either aide. Also look ... AH I see Mark's other question covers that ! :-) - ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to collect and re-check.  I've done this many times at Auckland.

The reason is immigration and customs is only at the Auckland international terminal.  NZ has strict controls on luggage - and will xray and scan them for food, wood, and many other restricted items.  You need to be with your luggage when this happens. If they checked it through for your domestic flight, then it wouldn't  go through customs.

Once you're through with your luggage into actual NZ, it's actually about a 1.2km (from memory) walk, or a free shuttle ride to the domestic terminal, where you'll get your flight to Queenstown.

When flying to Queenstown, if you can, [I recommend the left side of the plane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/which-side-of-the-plane-to-sit-on-an-auckland-akl-to-queenstown-zqn-flight?rq=1) - the view is spectacular.